# Holomorphic on the boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

I wonder what does it mean to extend holomorphically on the boundary. Let's say, one has $f(z)$ is a holomorphic function in $\{z: \mathrm{Re}(z) >0\}$. Then, suppose that $f(z)$ can be extended holomorphically to a closed region $\{z: \mathrm{Re}(z) \geq 0\}$. In this case, I have no clue what is the extra information that is given to us since I thought that the holomorphicity of a function is only defined on open set.

Comment: Where did you read such a thing?

Comment: I was trying to read Newman's short proof of the Prime number theorem and it contains an analytic theorem. I

Answer (score 1):

Let, $\Omega \subset\Bbb{C}$ be any subset.

$f$ is holomorphic on  $\Omega$ means $f$ is holomorphic on a open set containing $\Omega$

Comment: So it means to extend holomorphically to an open set that contains the set $\{z: \mathrm{Re}(z) \geq 0\}$ ?

Comment: I think so.... ...